# Add database name to the output of V$RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, rman

I am using the below command to get a single row output and my requirement is to have a first column as DB NAME followed by the selected columns below. How do I achieve it?

```
select SESSION_KEY, INPUT_TYPE, STATUS,
  to_char(START_TIME,'mm/dd/yy hh24:mi') start_time,
  to_char(END_TIME,'mm/dd/yy hh24:mi') end_time,
  TIME_TAKEN_DISPLAY
from V$RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS
where INPUT_TYPE like '%DB%'
and start_time = (select max(start_time) from V$RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the database name by joining to `v$database`, e.g.:

```
select d.name, rbjd.session_key, rbjd.input_type, status,
  to_char(rbjd.start_time,'mm/dd/yy hh24:mi') start_time,
  to_char(rbjd.end_time,'mm/dd/yy hh24:mi') end_time,
  rbjd.time_taken_display
from v$database d
cross join v$rman_backup_job_details rbjd
where rbjd.input_type like '%DB%'
and rbjd.start_time = (select max(start_time) from v$rman_backup_job_details);
```

Or with a subquery if you don't like the cross join, but I'm not a big fan of subqueries in the select list. And there are other ways to get the most recent row.

Answer (score 0):

This also can be used, As always  V$RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS output will be single row (as per the query given above).

```
select name,SESSION_KEY, INPUT_TYPE, STATUS,
  to_char(START_TIME,'mm/dd/yy hh24:mi') start_time,
  to_char(END_TIME,'mm/dd/yy hh24:mi') end_time,
  TIME_TAKEN_DISPLAY
from V$RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS,v$database
where INPUT_TYPE like '%DB%'
and start_time = (select max(start_time) from V$RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS)
```